# Ember: How Can I define an Item Controller in my Array Controller?

Tags: ember.js, controller

I've created a table in my app by iterating through a list of rows like this:

```
  {{#each visible_page itemController='ScheduledReport'}}
    .....
  {{/each}}
```

Now, I'm trying to abstract this table so that I can use it for more than just these reports.  So, I want to define the `itemController` in the `ArrayController` rather than  inlining it in the template:

```
App.ReportsScheduledController = App.TableController.extend(
  {
    itemController    : 'scheduledReport'
```

However, defining the `itemController` in the `ReportsScheduledController` -- which inherits from `Ember.ArrayController` -- doesn't render each row in the table.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in this setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the controller in the template for that to work.  Iterating over properties in the controller doesn't apply the wrapping of the item controller.

Comment: thanks. that seems to be the issue. It's too bad you can't iterate over a computed property -- `visible_page` in my case -- because I don't want all of `content` just a subset. Anyway, thanks for the answer.